# Java button location in property

Tags: java, properties

I have a problem 'cause i want to save button location (MainMenu.Menu_Options) into a properties file and read it too. How can i do this? I know i can use getLocation() but i need to transform it into a string. Code:

```
try{
        options.setProperty("firstbackcolor", firstbackgroundColor.toString());
        options.setProperty("secondbackcolor", secondbackgroundColor.toString());
        options.setProperty("firsttext", firsttextColor.toString());
        options.setProperty("secondtext", secondtextColor.toString());
        options.setProperty("Slot_Options", MainMenu.Menu_Options.getLocation());


        options.store(new FileOutputStream(SupremeDataPath),null);
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a properties file used to store a location you can do something like:

```
     // read from properties file
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        File file = new File("path here");
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String location = (String) properties.get("key.to.location");

    // write to properties file
    properties.setProperty("key.new.location", "new location");
    properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), "comment");
```

Comment: I need to write and read them. It could be in another file, but in only one if possible.

Comment: I added a snippet to add a new property (or override an existing property) in a file.